# In hangouts chat chatbot's cards http links opens the site using https

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-hangouts

I am writing a chatbot using googl apps script with google hangouts chat as the user interface.

In an interactive button, I have urls that use 'http' instead of 'https'. However, whenever I click on the link button, my browser (chrome) automatically redirects the link to 'https' and if the site happens not to support https, then it fails to open. (yes we still use http but the site that uses this protocol is for internal only...).

I checked [chrome://net-internals/#hsts] but there is nothing configured to force https.

Also when I paste some http:// address directly in the browser's address box, it properly opens the site usint http.

Is there any settings I am missing?

Please advise!

Additional info. When I use plain text object (not cards), then http links go to the specified links without using https.

```
 "buttons": [
              {
                "textButton": {
                  "text": "some text",
                  "onClick":{
                    "openLink":{
                      "url": "http://some.address" //Browser actually goes to https://some.address
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
```

Comment: As a work around, I am using short links that support https.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to use httpbin to redirect to the http page

```
https://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find some satisfying way

```
"url": "https://www.google.com/url?q=http://some.address"
```

Please try this, it will help you